# Logging in via modal using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication, bootstrap-modal

to be fair, I'm fairly new in the AJAX area (newbie to be more precise) and i think that i took quite a large bite entering that field.So, I'm struggling for a several days now trying to implement AJAX with my PHP script. Before you flag this question as duplicate please consider that I've tried every posted question from this site and not one solution pop out. That being said, here is what I want to achieve:  I want to show some sort of message after PHP script was successful or unsuccessful, something like picture below:

[image]

If there was successful show me msg, and redirect me (after 2 sec) to admin site, and if not show me error!

So, here is code for modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">test</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <form  id="myform" method="POST" role="form">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">User:</label>
            <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unesi korisnika">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            <input name="pass" type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unesi lozinku">
         </div>
         <div id="error">
            <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Error, try again!</strong> </div>
         </div>
         <div id="thanks">
            <div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Logging in..</strong></div>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitForm">Login!</button>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Here is my javascript block of code: Here I tried loging in using my php script but nothing happens, it's only showing me **#thanks** div when I start typing

```
$('#test').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(':input', '#myform').val("");
});

$("#thanks").hide();
$("#error").hide();

$("#myform").click(function (e) {
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: url,
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: 
         $("#thanks").show(),
        error: function () {
            $("#error").show();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my PHP **doLogin()** function inside myAuth class:

```
static function doLogin() {
    if(
        !empty($_POST['user'])
        &&
        !empty($_POST['pass'])
    ) {
        if(!session_id()) session_start();
        // check and retrive user with sended pass
        $user = self::_fetchUserWithPassDB();

        // if user found log in
        if($user) {
            // security


            $token = md5(rand(100000,999999));

            // save token in session
            $_SESSION["auth"] = $token;

            // save user in session
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user[0]["user"];

            // save role in session
            $_SESSION["role"] = $user[0]["role"];

            // postavi validity and token in cookie, session in base
            self::_setCookieSessionDBTokenValidity();                   
            // redirect on admin.php 
            header( "refresh:2;url=admin.php" );
        }
        else {

            header('Location:index.php');
        }

        if(!$user) {
            header("refresh:1;url=index.php" );
        }


    } // od if POST
```

and finally here is my **login.php**

```
<?php
// login.php
require_once('init.php'); 
myAuth::doLogin();

?>
```

Is it problem in in **doLogin**() function or is there problem with javascript, I really don't know? If there is any help, when I use this script without AJAX it works normal without any problems.

Like this:

```
<form  action="login.php" id="myform" method="POST" role="form">
....<!--rest of the modal form-->
```

### **UPDATE 1.**

I've tried something like this, but it does not work. Also, I've removed redirect from doLogin () and added in AJAX call but without any luck

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $("#thanks").show(), setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "admin.php";
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#error").show();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why don't avoid using serialize and pass the values directly ...

Comment: Nothing happens, just tested...thx anyway

Comment: you need to redirect to somewhere from your `success` callback, probably using `window.location`

Comment: Shouldn't `click` be `submit` ? And you will probably need to do redirection with javascript.

Comment: Tried this as well:     `$("#myform").submit(function (e) {
        var url = "login.php";
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: url,
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#thanks").show(),
                setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "admin.php";
            }, 2000);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#error").show();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });` Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I think that you have to use 'session_start()' always at the top of your script, before anything else..

Comment: I added as `session_start()`well but still, without any luck :( Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

```
<form  id="myform" method="POST" role="form">
```

outside of

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">
```

i.e.

```
<form  id="myform" method="POST" role="form">
    <div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently, your HTML is not valid (the start of `<form ...` lies inside `<div class="modal-body">` but the end of it is after the `modal-body` has ended. Your browser is probably cutting off the `<form` at the end of `modal-body` to follow valid HTML.

Comment: Ok, it works but only in redirecting(bigger chunk of problem was fixed to be fair).The problem is still lies in error handling. So, if I successfully login it triggers _success_ event but if the login was unsuccessful it still trigers `#thanks div` but nothing happens with redirect. Still, greate job man!! i upvoted your answer

Comment: If this has solved your main problem, you should accept it as the correct answer when you can. It looks like your other problem might be that the ending comma in `$("#thanks").show(),` should be a semicolon instead. It might help you to open browser tools in Google Chrome so that you can see any syntax errors that come up. If this doesn't solve your second problem, it would be best to open another question.

Comment: To be fair..it only solved half of the problem, I ll try to fix whole problem in reasonable amount of time if I don't succeed I ll mark your answer as  correct one. ( I tried `$("#thanks").show(),` but nothing changed...) once again, thx for help :)

Comment: Try a semicolon (`;`) instead of comma (`,`)